# Altering several divs into one

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this

```
str = testString.replace(/<div style="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/div><div style="\1">/g, '<div style="$1">$2<br>');
```

It removes

```
<div style="text-align: right;">text1</div>
<div style="text-align: right;">text2</div>
```

into

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
    text1<br>text2
</div>
```

Great!

What if i have multiple `<div>`'s?

How can i make

```
<div style="text-align: right;">text1</div>
<div style="text-align: right;">text2</div>
<div style="text-align: right;">text3</div>
<div style="text-align: right;">text4</div>
```

into

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
    text1<br>text2<br>text3<br>text4
</div>
```

?

Comment: mangling html with regexs is only going to lead to pain, misery, and heartbreak. you really need to learn how to use DOM manipulation to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thou cannot use regex for complex HTML manipulations! Please [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).
You could manipulate the DOM using jQuery to achieve the same result!

**[Please see this jsfiddle example for a possible alternative.](http://jsfiddle.net/6y5H2/)**

This is the jQuery code from the fiddle, assuming the requred divs are in a wrapping div with the id `toParse`.

```
$('body').ready(function() {

var template = $('#toParse div').first().clone();

var result = "";
$('#toParse div').each(function(index, element) {
    result += $(element).html();
    result += "<br/>";
});

// you can add some extra code here to remove that 
// extra final <br/>

$('#toParse').html($(template).html(result));
console.log(result); 
});​
```

Comment: Okay. How would you suggest doing it with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've already selected the `first` element from the DOM...

```
var next = first.nextElementSibling;

while (next && next.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "DIV") {
    first.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
    first.appendChild(next.firstChild)
    next = next.nextElementSibling
}
```

---

Just realized that we're not removing the empty divs from the DOM. If you wanted that, you can do this...

```
var next;

while ((next = first.nextElementSibling) && next.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "DIV") {
    first.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
    first.appendChild(next.firstChild)
    next.parentNode.removeChild(next);
}
```